# Is the rank of an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix $k-1$ if all of its principal minors of degree $k$ are zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the rank of an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix $\boldsymbol{H}$ equal to $k-1$ ($k<n$) if

1. all its $k\times k$ principal minors are zero, and
2. it has a nonzero $(k-1)\times(k-1)$ principal minor?

I am looking for a proof or counter example. Does anyone know of such a proof?

I am really struggling with the above statement. I know that if a Hermitian matrix has rank $k$ then there must at least be one principal minor of $\boldsymbol{H}$ of dimension $k$ that is not zero. See :
K.D. Ikramov, "On the ranks of principal submatrices of diagonalizable matrices", Journal of Mathematical Sciences, Vol. 157, No. 5, 2009, 595--596.

But how do you prove the above statement from this knowledge (or maybe it is not possible)?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out a flaw. Please see my edit. There exists at least one non-zero principal minor of $\boldsymbol{H}$ that has dimension $k-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known result and can be found, for example, [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=5_sxtcnvLhoC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=principal+submatrix+symmetric+matrix&source=bl&ots=ZofYuMgDEF&sig=voqe1jsXU_haJC7_musbYWEizCQ&hl=ro&ei=sUrES9--N8Oj_AbN24SsDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CDYQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=principal%20submatrix%20symmetric%20matrix&f=true).

You argument is not quite correct, but can be saved if you use some elementary row transformations (which doesn't affect the rank) in order to make the other $n-k$ rows equal to zero. Then note that the corresponding column transformations also make the corresponding columns equal to zero. Now use your argument.

Comment: Theorem 5.20 states. Let $\boldsymbol{H}$ be Hermitian. Then $\boldsymbol{H}$ has rank $r$ iff $\boldsymbol{H}$ has a nonsingular $r\times r$ principal submatrix $\boldsymbol{R}$, such that every principal submatrix of $\boldsymbol{H}$ containing $\boldsymbol{R}$ and one **or** two additional rows and columns is singular. My question is about the **or**. Is it **sufficient to add only one** column and row or must you also add a second column and row ($\forall$ possible principle submatrices containing $\boldsymbol{R}$). The same applies to Theorem 5.21.

Answer (score 0):

That there exists a principal minor of order $k-1$ which is non-zero suggests that there exists at least $k-1$ independent rows/columns
in $\boldsymbol{H}$. The rank of $\boldsymbol{H}$ is thus at least $k-1$. Assume that the rank of $\boldsymbol{H}$ is larger than $k$. If
the rank of $\boldsymbol{H}$ is larger than $k$, $\boldsymbol{H}$ must at least have $k$ independent rows/columns. Now assume that these $k$ independent
rows are selected and that their indexes are $i_1 \cdots i_k$. Now select the columns of $\boldsymbol{H}$ that correspond to the same indexes. Since,
$\boldsymbol{H}$ is Hermitian the columns will also be linearly independent [Ikramov2009]. Let $\boldsymbol{R}$ denote the $k\times k$ principal minor formed by the cross-section of 
the selected rows and columns. The principal minor $\boldsymbol{R}$ should be non-zero due to its construction. This contradicts the fact that all principal
minors of order $k$ are zero implying that the rank of $\boldsymbol{H}$ is $k-1$.

Comment: Please verify this proof be as thorough as possible. I am worried about one assumption in particular, if a minor is formed by the intersection of linear independent rows and columns is it non-zero?